# Symfony 3, проверка на повтор email и username

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Делаю регистрацию новых пользователей при помощи `FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()`.
При регистрации username и email должен быть уникальным и я, например для email в аннотации к классу User пишу

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="It looks like your already have an account!")
 */
 class User extends BaseUser
```

Тем самым, как я понял из документации, можно сделать проверку на уникальность поля `username`, но почему-то так не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу.

Comment: В опциях помоему это нужно указывать, когда регестрируйте бандл app/config/config.yml

Comment: В fosub по умолчанию уникальными полями являются username_canonical и email_canonical. Поэтому нет необходимости делать уникальным ещё и username. Но если очень хочется, то можно прописать уникальность через аннотацию `@ORM\AttributeOverride`. Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант использовать Validator. C помощью него вы сможете решить 3 задачи.
1. Значение будет проверятся на уникальность.
2. Можно добавить проверку на то что значение является email.
3. Поле не пустое. 
И самое прекрасное что это делается аннотациями и на это уходить не более 2х минут.

Вот [ссылка](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) на документацию где показано как сделать полю проверку на уникальность. Там в 1- ом примере реализовано сразу 2 проверки. 1 На уникальность, вторая на соответствие что это email/

Так же на всякий случай даю вам ссылку на класс [Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html).

Также обрати внимание в примере. есть заметка. Не забудь подключить класс.

> // DON'T forget this use statement!!! 
>   use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;